# Convert c++ struct to struct c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

i have a problem with convert a struct c++ to c# struct, i will leave the following code:

C++

```
struct SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG
{
bool    bEnable;        
int     iSensorType;    
SDK_EventHandler hEvent;    
};

struct SDK_EventHandler
{
unsigned int    dwRecord;               
int     iRecordLatch;               
unsigned int    dwTour;                     
unsigned int    dwSnapShot;             
unsigned int    dwAlarmOut;             
unsigned int    dwMatrix;               
int     iEventLatch;            
int     iAOLatch;                 
SDK_PtzLinkConfig PtzLink[NET_MAX_CHANNUM];     
SDK_CONFIG_WORKSHEET schedule;      

bool    bRecordEn;              
bool    bTourEn;                 
bool    bSnapEn;                    
bool    bAlarmOutEn;            
bool    bPtzEn;


bool    bTip;                       
bool    bMail;                      
bool    bMessage;                   
bool    bBeep;                      
bool    bVoice;                         
bool    bFTP;                   
bool    bMatrixEn;              
bool    bLog;                   
bool    bMessagetoNet;           

bool    bShowInfo;              
unsigned int    dwShowInfoMask;         
char    pAlarmInfo[8];

bool    bShortMsg;              
bool    bMultimediaMsg;         
};

struct SDK_PtzLinkConfig
{
int iType;      
int iValue;      
};


struct SDK_CONFIG_WORKSHEET
{   
SDK_TIMESECTION tsSchedule[6][7];
};

 struct SDK_TIMESECTION
    {

        int enable;
        int startHour;
        int startMinute;
        int startSecond;
        int endHour;
        int endMinute;
        int endSecond;
    };
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG
{
    public bool bEnable;
    public int iSensorType;
    public SDK_EventHandler hEvent;
};

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public struct SDK_EventHandler
{
   public ushort dwRecord;
   public int iRecordLatch;
   public ushort dwTour;
   public ushort dwSnapShot;
   public ushort dwAlarmOut;
   public ushort dwMatrix;
   public int iEventLatch;
   public int iAOLatch;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 32)]
   public SDK_PtzLinkConfig[] PtzLink;

   public SDK_CONFIG_WORKSHEET schedule;

   public bool bRecordEn;
   public bool bTourEn;
   public bool bSnapEn;
   public bool bAlarmOutEn;
   public bool bPtzEn;
   public bool bTip;
   public bool bMail;
   public bool bMessage;
   public bool bBeep;
   public bool bVoice;
   public bool bFTP;
   public bool bMatrixEn;
   public bool bLog;
   public bool bMessagetoNet;

   public bool bShowInfo;
   public ushort dwShowInfoMask;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
   public string pAlarmInfo;

   //public bool bShortMsg;
   //public bool bMultimediaMsg;         
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SDK_PtzLinkConfig
{
    public int iType;
    public int iValue;  
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SDK_CONFIG_WORKSHEET
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 6*7)]
    public SDK_TIMESECTION[] tsSchedule;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 struct SDK_TIMESECTION
    {

        public int enable;
        public int startHour;
        public int startMinute;
        public int startSecond;
        public int endHour;
        public int endMinute;
        public int endSecond;
    };
```

I'm calling this method:

C++:

```
long  H264_DVR_GetDevConfig(long lLoginID, unsigned long dwCommand, int nChannelNO, char * lpOutBuffer, unsigned long dwOutBufferSize, unsigned long* lpBytesReturned,int waittime = 1000);
```

C#:

```
 [DllImport("NetSdk.dll")]
        public static extern int H264_DVR_GetDevConfig(int lLoginID, uint dwCommand, int nChannelNO, IntPtr lpOutBuffer, 
            uint dwOutBufferSize, ref uint lpBytesReturned, int waittime);
```

I'm calling this way:

C#:

```
var vAlarmConfig = new SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG();

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG)));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(vAlarmConfig, ptr, true);
        uint lpBytesReturned = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG));
        int CHANNEL = 2;

        int result = XMSDK.H264_DVR_GetDevConfig(lLoginID, (uint)SDK_CONFIG_TYPE.E_SDK_CONFIG_ALARM_IN, CHANNEL, ptr,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SDK_ALARM_INPUTCONFIG)), ref lpBytesReturned, 10000);
```

Seems everything work fine, but when i run the program, the method return an illegal paramater.

What i'm doing wrong?. I think the problem is the conversion.

Regards.

Comment: `int` can mean different things depending on your C platform/compiler/settings. You need to start by figuring out what it means here.

Comment: I'm based my code from an example and they have int(c++) as int (c#), i proved some methods in my c# code and everything works except this.

Comment: @JonathanWood No. On Windows, `int` is the same in C# and C++.

Comment: It would be easier to declare the p/invokes using the C# struct types rather than `IntPtr`. Then you can let the marshaler do the work and you can avoid all those Marshal method calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C++ `bool` is a single byte. But the C# `bool` [default marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx) is as the 4 byte Winapi `BOOL` type. You'll need to add `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]` for every `bool` in your structs.

Your use of `ushort` is wrong. On the C++ side you have `unsigned int`. That is `uint` on the C# side.

You will also need to translate the structs accurately. Perhaps while you were debugging you made `pAlarmInfo` have length 64 rather than 8. Obviously you need to go back an do that correctly.

I guess you made that change because the struct size was incorrect. That should have been a tell-tale sign that there was a more serious problem. Your structs have to line up for each and every member. You can't just add a load of padding at the end to get the size right. If the sizes don't match then the layout will be wrong. You make the sizes match as a consequence of making the layouts match. When the latter is done correctly, the former happens as a consequence.

Comment: ok, i will do it the changes, by the way pAlarmInfo is 64 not 8, my mistake.

Comment: thanks for helping me, you are right, i changed ushort for uint and i made a little changes and the code it's working!!! :)